Reference to theories/books that support the human nature is ...?
I have read Violence, Trouble in Paradise by Slavoj Zizek and some other books on philosophy by writers including from my own country(India) like BR Ambedkar, Ramaswamy Periyar, Kancha Ilaiah etc.
In a talk of Zizek which I saw on youtube many years ago, he says this line " I think we all are monsters secretly" and talks of some points before and after this line to support the argument made in this line! Unfortunately, I am not able to find this exact video on youtube.
I have heard similar lines in some movies also which characters are introspecting or making wise remarks.

I want to read theories/books supporting this aspect of human nature. Can you please give me reference of such theories/ books?

Thanks!

See Zahi Zalloua, Being Posthuman: Ontologies of the Future (2021, Bloomsbury), page 8:

We might say, following Slavoj Žižek, that (the excess of) cruelty is “absolutely immanent, the very core of subjectivity itself.” It is part of our ontological makeup from the Old World to the New World. [...] There are, for instance, two ways to negate the statement “he is human.” We can say, “he is not human” and “he is inhuman.” But Žižek insists that the two are not the same:



“He is not human” means simply that he is external to humanity,
animal or divine, while “he is inhuman” means something thoroughly different, namely that he is neither human nor not human, but marked by a terrifying excess which, although negating what we understand as “humanity,” is inherent to being human [Slavoj Žižek, Less than Nothing: Hegel and the Shadow of Dialectical
Materialism (Verso, 2012)].



Why has this answer been downvoted? It would be helpful if the downvoter adds their reason.

You can try the book of essays, Monsters, Monstrosities, and the Monstrous in Culture & Society. I haven't read the book but the description on Amazon.com states:

Existing research on monsters acknowledges the deep impact monsters have especially on Politics, Gender, Life Sciences, Aesthetics and Philosophy. From Sigmund Freud’s essay ‘The Uncanny’ to Scott Poole’s ‘Monsters in America’, previous studies offer detailed insights about uncanny and immoral monsters. However, our anthology wants to overcome these restrictions by bringing together multidisciplinary authors with very different approaches to monsters and setting up variety and increasing diversification of thought as ‘guiding patterns’. Existing research hints that monsters are embedded in social and scientific exclusionary relationships but very seldom copes with them in detail.


Erving Goffman’s doesn’t explicitly talk about monsters in his book ‘Stigma’, but his study is an exceptional case which shows that monsters are stigmatized by society because of their deviations from norms, but they can form groups with fellow monsters and develop techniques for handling their stigma.

From what I'be read, I very much doubt Zizek would countenance taking his "I think we all are monsters secretly" at face value. The above book implicitly identifies "monsters" with the marginalised in society which become "monsters" to us. It's not a discussion of depravity in serial killers or rapists.
You might want to update your store of quotes.
